# Are there differences between Kants Categories and Aristotles?

Tags: kant, aristotle

Kant uses his philosophy to reconstruct Aristotles Categories; these enumerate all possible things that can be the predicate or the subject of a proposition.

Other than the reconstruction, are there any differences between Kants Categories and Aristotles?

Answer (score 3):

Kant does mention Aristotle's categories. However, Kant's interest in the categories was internal to his own system, and not an interest in reconstructing Aristotle. Kant's list of categories is quite different from Aristotle's.

Aristotle's categories are general-logical and metaphysical terms. He defines the categories as "what is signified by expressions which are in no way composite" (*Categories*, §4). His list consists of *ten* categories: substance, quantity, quality, relation, place, time, position, state, action, affection.

Kant's categories are logic-of-epistemology terms. He defines them as "conditions under which alone the manifold content of the sensuous intuitions can be united in one consciousness" (*Critique of Pure Reason*, Transcendental Logic, §16). His list consists of *twelve* categories, divided into four sets of three: (1) of quantity: unity, plurality, totality; (2) of quality: reality, negation, limitation; (3) of relation: substance- and- accident, cause- and- effect, reciprocity; (4) of modality: possibility, existence, necessity.